# How to load 20 latest file from each directory without reading all the file names

Tags: python, batch-file

I am trying to load only 'a' days file from today, if a =1 then only yestarday's file. I have around 350 folder. each folder has 1000s of .txt file of 1-11 kb. Everyday new files get added. I want to read only yesterday or last two day file. for each folder maximum of 5 files get added everyday. To read file for last n day i have written a code which works perfectly in local . The problem is the file are placed in a different server (\130.xx.xx.x\rtr) and it takes huge amount of time just t read all the file names. Please advice

Please advice how i can read latest 20 files from each folder.

```py
a = input("ener the no of days you want to download data from today   ")

for file in glob.glob('//130.xxx.xx.xxx/rtr/*/*.txt'):
    python_time = os.path.getmtime(file)
    #print(file)
    #print(datetime.fromtimestamp(python_time).date())
    diff =abs((datetime.fromtimestamp(python_time).date()-date.today()).days)
    #print(diff)
    if diff <= int(a) and diff >0:
        f = open(file, "r")
        #mycode
        print(2+3)
```

Comment: If you have access to that server, it'll be faster to list the files locally and then just send them to you (via ssh, for example)

Comment: Directories are usually stored in unsorted order. While this is often chronological, you can't use that reliably. Your best bet is to create a new sub-folder every time a new day starts.

Comment: @OferSadan No , it's sensitive financial data and can't be copied locally. As I said It took me less than a minute to complete the task(with dummy files of same size) where as it tooks 5 hours when connected to server.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I don't have control over that. can you please suggest something else which i can apply.

Comment: @ABD I think Ofen Sadan is suggesting you run the code on the server, not copy all the files locally. If you cannot run the code on the server, you could cache the file names locally. Do the files ever get updated? Can you predict where the new files will be or what name they will have?

Comment: @PeterSutton No the files once placed doesn't get changed. The files will be placed in any of the 375 folders. I can't predict the file names, no. I will try running the code in the server but not sure I have the access.   can i sort all the files then read the top 10/15 files, will that be faster?

Comment: @ABD Are new folders ever added? Are the txt files always 1-deep in the file tree? Or are there nested folders?

Comment: @PeterSutton new folders are seldom added. Yes they are 1 deep and not nested.

Comment: @ABD What version of python are you using?

Comment: @PeterSutton  Python 3.7.3

Comment: @PeterSutton any suggestion on how to load just 20 file in descening order from each folder?

Comment: @ADB I guess you need to reduce network requests. 1) Cache the top-level folder names. 2) For each folder, cache the txt file names and their mtime, only get the mtime for cache misses.

Comment: I tried copying the file using python to local but it was taking long so i used batch script to do it and it was Faster, much faster and the goal of loading only recent file are achieved.  i  used the below link to acheive copying the file.                           [link] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57865073/batch-file-to-copy-file-from-specific-sub-folder-inside-a-folder-to-destination/57869858#57869858