# Batch file to copy file from specific sub folder inside a folder to destination folder

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a folder structure like his

```
folder1-------|
              |123456------123.txt
                          abc.txt
              |234567------fgt.txt
                           234.txt
              |abc---------ytr.txt
                           1234.txt
```

I need to copy files from Main folders sub directories if the sub folder has a length of 6(only numbers) . So .txt files from 123456,234567 will be copied and abc will not be copied.

I have tried using wildcards but not succeed yet. Thanks in advance.

```
>xcopy /s "C:\Users\xxx.xxx\Desktop\folder1\*\*.txt" "C:\Users\xxx.xxx\Documents\New folder" /l /D:09-09-2019
```

Comment: use a for loop, test length of the string and whether they are numeric values, if true, copy the files.

Comment: @GerhardBarnard I have little to no experience with batch scripting. Thats why i asked for help. Thanks

Comment: Well, the code you posted does not really try to do what you describe, which makes this question off-topic here, because this is a site for questions and answers about a specific programming problem, but not to request code, neither is it a tutorial resource. So please learn [ask] and provide a [mcve] of your serious coding attempts. Thank you!

Comment: @aschipfl I am sorry if i offfend you . I needed help so i requested. I could understand what you are saying. It has been just few days since i joined so i am unaware of many things. Sorry

Comment: No no, all fine, no need to apologise; I just tried to explain how this site works and provided links to the most important help articles...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so here is an example:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /f %%i in ('dir "C:\Users\xxx.xxx\Desktop\folder1\" /b /ad') do (
  set "str=#%%i"
  set "len=0"
  for %%a in (4096 2048 1024 512 256 128 64 32 16 8 4 2 1) do (
    if "!str:~%%a,1!" neq "" (
       set /a "len+=%%a"
       set "str=!str:~%%a!"
       if !len! equ 6 if 1%%i equ +1%%i echo %%i is !len! characters   
     )
   )
)
```

This will do a `dir` of the directories inside the path you give it. It will then test the length of the string, if the length is 6 characters, it will then test if the string is numeric, if true, it will `echo` the string (folder name) and the length of it. You should then test it as is and if it gives you the required output, you can replace `echo` portion with your copy string.

So your final solution will be something like:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set /p "mydate=Enter Date (format dd-mm-yyyy): "
for /f %%i in ('dir "C:\Users\xxx.xxx\Desktop\folder1\" /b /ad') do (
  set "str=#%%i"
  set "len=0"
  for %%a in (4096 2048 1024 512 256 128 64 32 16 8 4 2 1) do (
    if "!str:~%%a,1!" neq "" (
       set /a "len+=%%a"
       set "str=!str:~%%a!"
       if !len! equ 6 if 1%%i equ +1%%i xcopy "C:\Users\xxx.xxx\Desktop\folder1\%%i\*.txt" "C:\Users\xxx.xxx\Documents\New folder" /D:!mydate! 
     )
   )
)
```

Comment: @ABD, see edit, I made a change to cater for possible octal strings and also added a prompt for the user to enter the date.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `FindStr` to isolate the directories matching your pattern:

[batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file):

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "SrcDir=%UserProfile%\Desktop\folder1"
Set "DstDir=%UserProfile%\Desktop\New folder"
For /F Delims^=^ EOL^= %%A In ('
    "Dir /B/AD "%SrcDir%\*" 2>NUL|FindStr "^[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]$""
')Do XCopy "%SrcDir%\%%A\*.txt" "%DstDir%\" /D:09-09-2019 /Y>NUL 2>&1
```

Just modify the paths between the **`=`** and **`"`** on lines `2` and `3` to suit your actual source and destination directories.

Comment: I had not used the solution you provided yet hence hadn't replied . It is indeed working with less or no changes to the code you have provided. I am going to work on a unc path which has tens of thousands of file. I will surely update if this help speed up the execution.

Comment: can i ask the date input from the user and make it dynamic?

Comment: Of course you can, however as you've selected another answer, and this would technically be another question, I'd be reluctant to expand upon my current answer. You can request input using `Set /P "DateMask=Please enter your date in the format MM-DD-YYYY: "`, then you could replace, `/D:09-09-2019` with `/D:%DateMask%`. It is important to note that to do this robustly, as the end user can enter nothing or anything at the input prompt, you should perform a verification routine on that input before proceeding with the rest of your script.

Answer (score 1):

Here is yet another method to achieve what you want (see all the explanatory `rem` remarks):

```cmd
@echo off
rem // Use a `for /D` loop to iterate through all immediate sub-directories in the given root directory:
for /D %%I in ("%UserProfile%\Desktop\folder1\*") do (
    rem // Store path and name of currently iterated directory in variables:
    set "DIRECTORY=%%~I" & set "NAME=%%~nxI"
    rem // Toggle delayed expansion to be able to write and to read a variable within the same block of code:
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    rem // Check if directory name holds more than 5 characters:
    if not "!NAME:~5!" == "" (
        rem // Check if directory name holds not more than 6 characters:
        if "!NAME:~0,6!" == "!NAME!" (
            rem // The directory name is exactly 6 characters long.
            rem // Check whether the directory name consists of decimal figures by (mis-)using a `for /F` loop:
            set "FLAG=" & for /F "tokens=1 delims=0123456789 eol=0" %%J in ("!NAME!") do set "FLAG=#"
            rem // The flag variable has not been set, hence the directory name consists of decimal figures:
            if not defined FLAG (
                rem // Do the actual copy job at this point:
                xcopy /I /Y /D:09-09-2019 "!DIRECTORY!\*.txt" "!UserProfile!\Documents\New Folder"
            )
        )
    )
    endlocal
)
```

You were trying to use [wildcards](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-wildcards.html) not only in the last element of a path, which cannot be done (in Windows), but you can use a [`for /D` loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for_d.html) to resolve the wildcards in upper directory levels, as demonstrated in the script.

The script uses [`~`-modifiers](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html) (which are the same for `for` meta-variables like `%%I` and for argument references like `%1`) to get the pure name of the currently iterated directory: `%%~nxI`.

To determine whether or not the directory name is exactly six (6) characters long, [sub-string expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html) is applied.

To determine whether or not the directory name consists of decimal digits only, a [`for /F` loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html) is (mis-)used: `for /F` splits strings into parts at given delimiter characters (option `delims`); since all decimal digits are defined as delimiters, a directory named `1a2b3c` would be split into the parts `a`, `b` and `c` (`a` becomes assigned to `%%J` then due to `tokens=1`, the other parts become dismissed), but a directory name `123456` leaves nothing behind since this is a delimiter-only string, in which case the `for /F` loop does not iterate at all. Together with a flag-like variable `FLAG` that becomes set in the body of the `for /F` loop we are able to determine whether or not the loop iterated, thus knowing whether the current directory name only consists of decimal digits.

The script writes to and reads from the variable `NAME` in the same block of code, which can normally not be done, unless you enable [delayed variable expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html).

You can use the [system environment variable `%UserProfile%`](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-variables.html) instead of specifying `C:\Users\xxx.xxx`, so the script may even work on a system where the user profile directory is not at the default location.

Comment: Thank you for a detailed explanation. I learnt a lot from this thread alone and see how the SO is such an awesome community.